# Effective version of the Bombieri-Vinogradov theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, asymptotics

Is there an effective version of the Bombieri-Vinogradov Theorem, in that have bounds on the implied constant been found?

Comment: For effective *variants* of Bombieri--Vinogradov, see e.g. this paper of Akbary and Hambrook:
http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~akbary/Akbary-Hambrook.pdf
or Lemma 5.2 of this paper of Lenstra and Pomerance:
https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/complexity12.pdf